# Issue In @import using sass in scss file

Tags: import, sass

I am using these files for my projects
https://github.com/anasnakawa/bi-app-sass
I done all things what its said but i have a problem using sass
when i use @import its giving me error here what i am doing.
[image]

But here is error please let me know where i am wrong

[image]

Comment: Why would you post a screenshot of the code/error?  Search engines can't search images.

Answer (score 1):

'bi-app-ltr' is in a different folder. It should be

```
@import '../../bi-app/bi-app-ltr';
```